# Array to LinkedList in C++

Tags: c++, linked-list

Hi everyone trying to translate an older C program that uses array of structures into C++ program that uses linked lists. I'm a total C++ newb and I'm a little confused on the syntax of setting up a linked list in C++.... here's my code:

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;


struct Video { 
char video_name[1024];      
int ranking;                // Number of viewer hits
char url[1024];             // Video URL
struct Video *next;  // pointer to Video structure
} 


struct Video* Collection = new struct Video;
Collection *head = NULL;                    // EMPTY linked list
```

In my old program `Collection` was an array of `Video`. How can I make `Collection` be a linkedlist of `Video` nodes? I am currently getting errors saying on the last two lines code saying: `expected initializer before 'Collection'` and `expected constructor, destructor or type conversion before '*' conversion`. I know my syntax is definately wrong, but I guess I dont understand how to create a linked list of Videos inside of Collection...

Comment: If you don't know how to implement a linked list, use the STL's List class

Comment: **Get a book !! Get a book !!** Here is some help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list

Comment: @SidharthMudgal Indeed, even if you *do* know how to implement a linked list, STL's will be solid, tested, and optimized, and with lots of useful helper functions like std::sort already there. Except as a learning exercise, there is *zero* reason to be writing your own linked list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The c++ answer is:

```
struct Video { 
    std::string video_name;     
    int ranking;                // Number of viewer hits
    std::string url;             // Video URL
} 

std::list<Video> list_of_videos
```

Comment: Agreed -- use STL rather than implementing from scratch

Comment: I agree.  Here's a link for ease of use: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list

Answer (score 0):

You've defined `Collection` as a variable of type pointer-to-Video. On the next line you treat it as a type, which makes no sense. All you need is this:

```
Video *head = NULL;
```

`head` represents the linked list. You don't need another variable.

OTOH, if you really want to use C++ properly, I'd suggested sticking with the array solution unless your usage patterns somehow warrant linked-list semantics. If it's an array of known size, you have two choices:

```
Video videos[N];
std::array<Video, N> videos; // Preferred in C++11
```

Otherwise, use a `std::vector<T>`:

```
std::vector<Video> videos;
```

If it really must be a linked list, consider using `std::list<T>`:

```
std::list<Video> videos;
```

In all such cases, you should leave out `struct Video *next;`.